# Can a disregarded entity carry forward a tax loss?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, limited-liability-company, form-1040

I've heard that in general only businesses can carry tax loss forward (though in certain cases individuals can, too). Can someone filing taxes as an individual because they have a business which is a disregarded entity (a single member LLC) carry a loss?

<sub>(Also, what is this 80% limit? If there is a net loss, 80% of it will *always* be higher than 80% of the profits since the profits are 0!)</sub>

Comment: It is a disregarded entity.

Comment: @gaefan Thanks. Corrected now. It took me a moment to realize what you meant. At first I thought you were telling me that a single member LLC is a disregarded entity :)

Comment: Well, that too.  A single member LLC is usually a disregarded entity unless you've opted for S-corp taxation.

Comment: FOR US (implied by your tags though not stated) YES an individual with a loss from a disregarded LLC (and some other sources) can carry it forward with some limitations. _Formerly_ you could elect to carry back 2 years before carrying forward, but that has been repealed. See [IRS publication 536](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p536) (also available in PDF, which I personally prefer, by navigating up one level at the top of the page)